# How do I install ubuntu 20.04 LTS on a laptop without accessing the BIOS?

Tags: boot, 20.04

My friend wants to install ubuntu on his old spare pc to test it out. He asked me how to do it. I told him to download the iso and made him go through the process. Then, he told me his F2 key is broken and he can't access the BIOS. How do I install ubuntu? I tried UNetBootin but it didn't support 20.04. Please help!
Edit: It's on legacy mode and simply putting in the usb didn't work.

Comment: Borrow a different keyboard for the install.

Comment: Besides using an external keyboard, if it has an optical drive, burn the iso onto a DVD and hope it comes first in the boot order...

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the model of laptop it is possible it has an option to display a boot options menu instead of accessing the bios.

HP machines for example use F10 for the bios but pressing F9 will show a list of available bootable drives to choose from.

Below is from [here](https://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/bios-keys-to-access-your-firmware,5732.html) which has other options if these don't work.

```
ASRock: F2 or DEL
ASUS: F2 for all PCs, F2 or DEL for Motherboards
Acer: F2 or DEL
Dell: F2 or F12
ECS: DEL
Gigabyte / Aorus: F2 or DEL
HP: F10
Lenovo (Consumer Laptops): F2 or Fn + F2
Lenovo (Desktops): F1
Lenovo (ThinkPads): Enter then F1.
MSI: DEL for motherboards and PCs
Microsoft Surface Tablets: Press and hold volume up button.
Origin PC: F2
Samsung: F2
Toshiba: F2
Zotac: DEL
```